# how to get rid of buitin quotation in an array and save into file

Tags: python, file

I have a two-dimensional array like this:

```
  [["x","0xacc2d9"],
  ["y","0x56ae57"]]
```

I want to save this array such that it keeps the two-dimensional array.
first item with the quotation, second item  WIthout quotation.

So the result saved in the file should be:

```
 [["x",0xacc2d9],
  ["y",0x56ae57]]
```

I tried various ways, but as the quotation is not something extra and is buitin I can not remove it.
I have tried.

```
lst. replace(""",")
```

Also,this one:

```
filename= 'test.txt'
 with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

But it removes [] , "", which I do not want to remove them.

Thanks for helping.

**Edit2**
For some reason, I need my output **have double quotation**, **not single quotation** so the output has to be: which x has `double quotation`

```
   [["x",0xacc2d9],
      ["y",0x56ae57]]
```

Comment: You aren't outputting CSV data; don't use `csv.writer`.

Comment: @chepner thanks for answering. but I have tried various ways but I could not get my desired output. can you please let me know your idea how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfect, but it gives you something to play with:

```
In [883]: lst =  [["x","0xacc2d9"], 
     ...:   ["y","0x56ae57"]]  
In [885]: with open('test.txt','w') as f: 
     ...:     f.write('[') 
     ...:     for row in lst: 
     ...:         f.write('[%r, %s]\n'%tuple(row)) 
     ...:     f.write(']\n') 
     ...:                                                                       
In [886]: cat test.txt                                                          
[['x', 0xacc2d9]
['y', 0x56ae57]
]
```

How do you plan on using this file?

And for a bit cleaner handling of the out brackets (and quote replacement):

```
In [887]: astr = '\n'.join(['[%r, %s]'%tuple(row) for row in lst])              
In [888]: astr                                                                  
Out[888]: "['x', 0xacc2d9]\n['y', 0x56ae57]"
In [895]: astr = astr.replace("'",'"')                                          
In [896]: astr                                                                  
Out[896]: '["x", 0xacc2d9]\n["y", 0x56ae57]'
In [897]: with open('test.txt','w') as f: 
     ...:     print('[%s]'%astr, file=f) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [898]: cat test.txt                                                          
[["x", 0xacc2d9]
["y", 0x56ae57]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @hpaulj . sorry for not being clear, for some reason I only want double quotation in the result. so x  will be "x" not 'x', can you please let me know if you have any idea for fixing it?

Comment: It is for specific usage in another area, that's why I have to prepare the correct formatting.  Do you have any idea how can we have the first item with a double quotation?

Comment: I added an alternative with quote replacement.  There may also be a way of controling the choice of quotes in either the `%` of `.format` formatting mechanisms.  We'd have to dig around for that.  Python uses the two versions interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did use the replace to replace ' to " but it did not work!!. again thanks so much. you helped  alot :)